# Chain rule festival, show $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = z-xy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

$z=z(x,y)$ is a positive differentiable function defined on $W=\{(x,y): x,y >0\}$, such that $F(x+\frac{z}{y}, y+\frac{z}{x}) = 0$, where $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and $\nabla F \neq 0$.

Show that $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = z-xy$

**What I did:**

I derived using the chain rule and hoped to show what we wanted. Derive $F(x+\frac{z}{y}, y+\frac{z}{x}) = 0$ wrt both variables. First $x$:

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial(x+\frac{z}{y})}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial(y+\frac{z}{x})}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(1+\frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-z}{x^2} = 0$

and $y$ similarly $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}-z}{y^2} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(1+\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})=0$

I was hoping by adding or subtracting these equations something cancels out (most importantly the derivatives of $F$), but no dice.

How do we continue? why is it important that $z$ is positive and what $W$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rule says that
$$
0=\nabla F\!\left(x+\frac zy,y+\frac zx\right)\cdot\left[\left(1+\frac{z_x}y,\frac{z_x}x-\frac{z}{x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x+\left(\frac{z_y}y-\frac{z}{y^2},1+\frac{z_y}x\right)\mathrm{d}y\right]
$$
for any $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$

This means that both 
$$
\left(1+\frac{z_x}y,\frac{z_x}x-\frac{z}{x^2}\right)
$$
and
$$
\left(\frac{z_y}y-\frac{z}{y^2},1+\frac{z_y}x\right)
$$
are perpendicular to
$$
\nabla F\!\left(x+\frac zy,y+\frac zx\right)
$$
and are thus, parallel. This means that
$$
\left(1+\frac{z_x}y\right)\left(1+\frac{z_y}x\right)
=\left(\frac{z_x}x-\frac{z}{x^2}\right)\left(\frac{z_y}y-\frac{z}{y^2}\right)\\
\Downarrow\\
1+\frac{z_x}y+\frac{z_y}x
=\left(-\frac{z_x}{y}-\frac{z_y}{x}+\frac{z}{xy}\right)\frac{z}{xy}\\
\Downarrow\\
\left(\frac{z}{xy}+1\right)\left(\frac{z_x}y+\frac{z_y}x\right)=\frac{z^2}{x^2y^2}-1\\
\Downarrow\\
\frac{z_x}y+\frac{z_y}x=\frac{z}{xy}-1\\
\Downarrow\\
x\,z_x+y\,z_y=z-xy
$$